# Mysql count and group between specific dates

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, between

I have a problem with a query.

I have a table like this:
tbl_people

```
id | startDate  | endDate    | Gender
1  | 2010-03-01 | 2011-04-11 | m
2  | 2010-04-01 | 2010-06-14 | f
3  | 2010-03-01 | 2010-04-11 | m
4  | 2009-09-09 | 2009-10-10 | f
```

For all years given in the database I want to count the gender of the people, for who that year is between startDate and endDate. When startDate is 2010 and endDate 2011 it should count for both.

So the result should look like this:

```
year | m | f | m+f
2009 | 0 | 1 | 1
2010 | 2 | 1 | 3
2011 | 1 | 0 | 1
```

I have no really good idea how to realize that query for a list of all years.
Currently I have this:

```
select
    sum(case tbl_people.Gender when 'm' then 1 else 0 end),
    sum(case tbl_people.Gender when 'f' then 1 else 0 end),
    count( tbl_people.Gender )
...
```

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join with a table that contains all the years. You can either create a real table with all the years, or construct it on the fly in a subquery:

```
SELECT y.year, 
        SUM(p.Gender = 'm') AS m,
        SUM(p.Gender = 'f') AS f,
        COUNT(*) AS `m+f`
FROM (SELECT 2009 AS year
      UNION
      SELECT 2010 AS year
      UNION
      SELECT 2011 AS year) AS y
LEFT JOIN tbl_people AS p ON y.year BETWEEN YEAR(p.startDate) AND YEAR(p.endDate)
GROUP BY y.year
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2ef/1)